# UICollectionView Cards like view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make cards like view(not like Tinder) similar to safari but not exactly the same.
I have started with something, and wonder how to continue doing it with a simple collection view, where the views are moving

First, this is how it should look like as you scroll you go from 1 to 4):
[image]

How can you achieve that using a collection view ? moving the cells to cover each other

Comment: r u looking for only 3 cells ?

Comment: but after some scroll you will end up with screen having all those little color bars tucked in, then how will you manage the scroll ?

Comment: i think u should only keep the last one as that little color bars...at the 4th pic the orange one gone...then that easier to solve